# Mobilefirst Push Notification doesn't work if app closed

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm working with MF CLI version 7.1. I've used Push Notification Sample from Mobile first and everything is going fine, but In my case I'm able to subscribe and receive push notifications.

But when I close the app I'm not able to receive push notification once I open the app the notification appears. The adapter message returned is with a positive result.

my device : Api level 6.

the project : 
https://github.com/vivinkrishnan/multi-line-push

Answer (score 0):

API level 6 translates to Android 2.0.1 which is not supported in MobileFirst. Try again in newer devices such as those starting with API level 10 (Android 2.2).

Comment: I mean : Android 6.0 APIs